# Actualizar div sin actualizar página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un sistema de comercio electrónico desde el cual cada solicitud hace una notificación sólida.

```
<audio id="notificacao" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://adm.pingodelivery.com.br/sistema/notificacao/alerta.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script>
    $(function() { 
     function toque() {
        $.get("atualizar.php", function (result) {     
            console.log();
            if(result == 1){
              $('#notification').trigger('play');                 
            }
        });
      }   
    toque();
    //$(window).load(function () { $("#pedidos").setInterval(3000); })
    setInterval(toque, 3000);    
    });
</script>
```

Pero me gustaría que toques el sonido, actualices el div a continuación que está en la misma página.

```
<div id="pedidos">
<?php echo $métodos->pedidos(); ?>
</div>
```

¿Cómo actualizo el div **pedidos** al mismo tiempo que se reproduce el sonido?

Comment: A qué te refieres con actualizar? Quieres decir que aparezca el div, o qué es lo que se tendría que actualizar?

Comment: Ola Sr1871. Debe ser actualizado.

Comment: Me gustaría actualizer el div "pedidos" al mismo tempo que la "function toque()". Perdona mi español.

Comment: Agrega mas detalle a tu pregunta, agrega la respuesta o la data con la que quieres que se actualice tu div.

Comment: La respuesta puede ser el asíncronismo y para ello te puedes apoyar en `ajax` o `fetch`. En la comunidad encuentras muchos ejemplos de cómo usarlos.